# Flex container with scroll without fixed height

Tags: html, css

I have a container that has to be the height of the window. Inside, there are some elements (yellow, lime and red). The red container has a header (green) and a blue container that contains smaller elements. This blue container is the one that should have the scroll. All elements should not go past the window height (so that there is no scrollbar on the window itself). I hope I made this clear enough to understand.

```
.blue{
  flex:1 1;
  overflow:auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(155px,1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 1.25rem;
  grid-row-gap: 1.25rem;
  padding:10px;
  background:blue;
}
.blue .item{
    transition: background .2s,box-shadow .3s;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    height: 175px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #1C2127;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    user-select: none;
}
```

How do I make the blue container fill the remaining space with flex, and have a scrollbar inside?

I'm trying to solve this issue but it doesn't seem to work. I've made a codepen for this question:

https://codepen.io/nedasoo/pen/PoqdOyr

Thanks

Comment: `flex:1 0 0;` on the `.blue` this means the blue div will be stretched to fill the empty space first then it's content will be laid out, this ensure the blue div to stay within it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

The `flex-basis: 0` style has been added

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0
}
.container{
  height:100%;
  background-color:grey;
  width:500px; /* For demonstration purposes, I've changed '800px' to '500px' */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.yellow{
  background:yellow;
  height:80px;
}
.lime{
  background:lime;
  height:80px;
}
.red{
  background:red;
  flex:1 1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.green{
  flex:0;
  background:green;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
.blue{
  flex:1 1; /* You can also add `0` here */
  flex-basis: 0; /* You can also add '0' after the abbreviation 'flex', flex: 1, 1, 0;*/
  min-height: 50px; /* For demonstration purposes, I've added the 'min-height: 50px' style */ 
  overflow:auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(155px,1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 1.25rem;
  grid-row-gap: 1.25rem;
  padding:10px;
  background:blue;
}
.blue .item{
  transition: background .2s,box-shadow .3s;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  height: 175px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #1C2127;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='yellow'>Yellow</div>
  <div class='lime'>Lime</div>
  <div class='red'>
    <div class='green'>Some text here</div>
    <div class='blue'>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```